# Como solucionar el error "Unable to connect to the remote server" usando FtpWebRequest

Tags: c#, asp.net, ftp, .net-core

estoy subiendo archivos a una carpeta FTP, cuando lo pruebo localmente, se conecta al servidor FTP correctamente y sube el archivo. pero cuando publico el proyecto, e intento subir un archivo, me tira el error "Unable to connect to the remote server"

```
                            using (var ms = new MemoryStream()) {
                                resized.Save(ms, ImageFormat.Jpeg);

                                string ftpUrl = "ftp://" + (await _context.Configuración.Where(c => c.Parámetro == "FTP de Objetos Multimedia").FirstAsync()).Valor + "/" + fileName;
                                string ftpUsr = (await _context.Configuración.Where(c => c.Parámetro == "FTP usuario").FirstAsync()).Valor;
                                string ftpPss = (await _context.Configuración.Where(c => c.Parámetro == "FTP contraseña").FirstAsync()).Valor;

                                FtpWebRequest request = (FtpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(ftpUrl);
                                    request.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(ftpUsr, ftpPss);
                                    request.UsePassive = true;
                                    request.UseBinary = true;
                                    request.KeepAlive = false;
                                    request.EnableSsl = false;
                                    request.Timeout = 3000000;
                                    request.ContentLength = ms.Length;
                                    request.ServicePoint.ConnectionLimit = Convert.ToInt32(ms.Length);
                                    request.Proxy = null;
                                    request.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.UploadFile;

                                byte[] buffer = new byte[ms.Length];

                                ms.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
                                ms.Close();

                                Stream reqStream = request.GetRequestStream();
                                reqStream.Write(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
                                reqStream.Close();
                            }
```

me estoy conectando al mismo FTP, con el mismo usuario y contraseña, se me ocurre que el error no esta en el FTP, sino en donde estoy ejecutando el proyecto. algun permiso, no se. 
si alguno me puede orientar, se los voy a agradecer. ;)

Comment: lo primero es revisar que desde donde se esta ejecutando el proyecto pueda ver la ip del servidor FTP, ya sea con un `ping`o un `telnet`

Comment: voy a ver si puedo probar eso de alguna forma, estoy ejecutandolo en smarterasp.net, y el ftp esta tambien ahi...

Comment: le escribi al soporte de smarterasp.net y me dicen que no soportan FTP en el codigo del proyecto. me dicen que use ASPUpload. hay forma de usar eso en c#? es asp classico. no?

Comment: De parte mia, desconozco el tema.

Comment: Básicamente lo que te ha dicho soporte es que utilices un "FileUploader", ¿con qué versión de asp.net core estás?

Comment: estoy con ASP.NET Core 3.0 MVC C#

Comment: Hola Diego y pudiste solucionar el inconveniente ahora me estoy topando con un error similar de manera local funciona y sube al ftp correspondiente pero cuando lo publico me sale el mismo inconveniente que tuviste.

Comment: estaba usando smarterasp.net como proveedor y ellos tenían limitado el servicio, ya no recuerdo bien, pero se que no pude con este código y tuve que cambiarlo. si no estas apurado, cuando tenga un tiempo lo busco y te paso lo que termine haciendo